# How to loop CDATA Fields in JS (Foreach)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, foreach

I have a list of widgets in wordpress. One of those widgets is a slider. As the slider needs the ID and other information, I am parsing a cdata array to the website using the wp_localize_script - one for every slider. So in my site, right after the footer element, i have the following code (example)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var sliderID = {"slider":"57d7b035941e9"};
var sliderID = {"slider":"57d7b03596340"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Each number is a php "uniqid();"-number to set a unique ID for the slider. I am also loading a "sliderscripts.js" to the footer if the slider is active in the current site (in the footer, but below the CDATA). In the sliderscripts.js I now want to make a slider foreach ID. Using the ID is no problem like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#'+sliderID.slider).owlCarousel({
... my options ...
});
```

Now the question:
How can I, using JS, loop that? If it would be

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var sliderID = {"slider":"57d7b035941e9","slider":"57d7b03596340"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

there wouldnt be a problem. I need to foreach CDATA with var SliderID do something.  Would be great if you help me!

thank you!

Comment: Your first code doesn’t make much sense, since you are overwriting the `sliderID` variable with a new value, so only the last one survives.

Comment: And btw., I am pretty sure that you don’t need to initialize owl carousel for each item individually via an id … it should work just as well, if you select multiple elements, f.e. via a common class.

Comment: Hi @CBroe - thank you for your fast reply. 1. Ok so this is my error - I am using the function for the first time and I am not familiar with CDATA. Do you have any better solution?

2. The slider also has options like "show bullets" or "show nav-arrow". So i have to use the ID as every slider could be slightly differnt.

Hoping for you to reply and help me ;)

Comment: First of all, this has nothing to do with CDATA at all; it is just used here as a very conservative way of embedding JavaScript. And if you need other individual options/settings for each slider as well, then where are those? You need to “connect” them with the right slider/right id somehow, how are you planning on doing that? You should think about a proper data structure first. I’d collect all settings in an array (using the slider id as key, or as an additional property), and then output that as JSON, so that the client-side JS has something that can easily be looped over.

Comment: Hi @CBroe as I wrote above the pasted code is an example which has been shortened for better reading, of course my CDATA now delivers info like bullets, timing, animation, arrows,... not only the ID. But an example for the ID would be enough to make all other values by my own. I am looking for someone to teach me, not someone to code for me (as many others over here). So your input was great. thank you so far. I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if @CBroe had a great idea, it was way too much work to start by 0. For others with the same problem, this is my solution:

**1. Generate ID**

```
$sid = uniqid(); // sid = slider-ID - FE: 123
```

will generate a unique ID for every slider

**2. Generate Password**

As I've been told not to use uniqid multiple times in a function (it should work but it seems to be a bad technique?) I am using the wordpress hook generate password to generate an ID-similar element.

```
$ID2 = wp_generate_password(20, false, false); // generates an password / ID with 20 digits. FE: 12345678912345678911
```

**3. Add ID and data-attribut to the code**

I now open the owlslider code like

```
<div id="slider_<?php echo $sid; ?>" class="owls" data-id2="<?php echo $ID2; ?>"
```

**4. Localize Script**

Now I am also localizing these values, so I can get them with JS

```
$slidersettings = array(
    'slider' => $sid,
    'url' => plugins_url(),
);
$sliderhandle = 'sl_'.$ID2; // will be sl_12345678912345678911

wp_localize_script( 'slider', $sliderhandle, $slidersettings );
```

**5. Build Slider.**

Last but not least I enqueue a custom script where I check for the IDs to set every slider like this

```
// check for all div's with the class "owls" AND id starts with "slider"
$('div.owls[id^="slider"]').each( function() { 
    var $div = $(this);
    var ID2 = $div.data('ID2'); // Now I grab the ID2 / 2nd ID out of the data-attribute


var cdata = window['sl_' + ID2]; // this now tells me in which CDATA Array I have to look for my values

$install= $( '#slider_' + cdata.slider); // slider_123 <- 123 = uniqid.

        $install.owlCarousel({
... standard owl stuff here...
})
```

thats it. Hope this will help someone else sometime.... all the best